# Kernel estimation of hazard or density function

Tags: r, survival, kernel-smoothing, hazard

I am working with R package "muhaz" to get the kernel estimate of the hazard function. If we have the following example which is the sample of uncensored data:

```
    x =c(0.001409591, 0.008451294, 0.019719245, 0.046626865 ,0.244813744,
       0.410032119, 0.489286425, 0.697342699, 0.731541987, 0.954493031)
    fit = muhaz(x, rep(1, length(x)), bw.method="local", b.cor="both", n.min.grid=51,
    n.est.grid=101, kern="epanechnikov")
```

I have two questions:
1) How can I write the estimated hazard function as a formula in terms of the result of fit?
How can we get the estimated hazard function for any desire value not just for grid points (fit$est.grid points)?

2) Is it possible to get the estimated density function? because as far as I know the result does not provide it. How can we get the estimated density function for any desire value? not just for grid points (fit$est.grid points).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is essentially a request for advice on how to use an R package. See the help center for advice on software-related questions.